Movie where a painting shows the cemetery in front of the house, with a dead man returning to life
I saw this movie some 20 or 30 years ago, don't remember if it was b&w (it was already old then). There was a man who lived in front of the cemetery. There was a ladder in his living room, right in front of the main door, and in the top of it a painting of the house, with the cemetery in front. In a certain point (close to the end of the movie?), the painting was showing what was going outside the house (not sure if the painting was "alive" the whole movie) - a corpse getting up from a graveyard and walking slowly in the direction of the front door. When the body in the painting gets to the door, we hear a knock on the door, and that's kind of the climax of horror in the movie, if I remember right. Anyone knows which movie is this?

It's actually a Night Gallery episode called "The Cemetery."
A seemingly haunted painting drives a greedy man insane.
"The Cemetery," involves a black sheep nephew (Roddy McDowall) who murders his rich uncle to inherit his fortune - both much to the detriment of the uncle's butler (Ossie Davis), only to find that vengeance extends beyond the grave.

Full episode on DailyMotion.  

Yes, that's it. And the link is good, if we ignore the same annoying 30s of ad every four minutes... Thank you!
